# How to get foreign AD object from my domain controller?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using Powershell 7, I am reading permissions set on file shares (the NTFS permissions) and then listing the users and groups. I'm trying to get the full name of the user account and members of groups. This works fine when the principal is an Active Directory object in the same domain as my local host and my user account. But when the object is in a trusted/trusting domain, that's another matter. It would undoubtedly work fine if my computer had direct access to the domain controller in the foreign domain, but the firewall blocks that. So, is there a way to make a call to my domain controller to ask it to get that information for me (other than just running a command on my domain controller remotely)?

Comment: Please include your current code that fetches the NTFS permissions